# How to get an AUC plot for Cox Regression?

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, roc, auc

[image]

This is a figure for survival analysis on a dataset. The article is [found at this link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5519051/)

I am self teaching survival analysis. Up until recently, I believed that AUC and ROC were only for classification. How are AUC curves computed for survival times? I'd like to remake this.

The data is found

[at this second link](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Heart+failure+clinical+records)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The legend in the plot shows that the curves correspond to specific time points.  Survival models (Cox PH, parametric regression, etc.) can give predictions of the probability of surviving at a given time.  So I expect for that plot they computed the predicted survival for each subject at times 50 days and 250 days, then used those probabilities (compared to actual outcome at that time) to compute the ROC curves just like if the probabilities had come from a logistic regression or other classification tool.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Do you know which packages in R could have done that?

Comment: That's correct (+1), although care has to be taken with respect to handling censored observations. [This paper](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.0006-341X.2005.030814.x) is cited in the paper linked in the question; the [`risksetROC` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=risksetROC) seems to correspond to that citation. The R [survival task view](https://cran.r-project.org/view=Survival) shows several implementations of ROC under "Predictions and Prediction Performance."